# Exporting RSA Private Key + Certificate with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

**Software**: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7

A long time ago, I created a single PEM file which contained two blocks.
**RSA Private Key**, and **Certificate**.

I've created new certificates and I need to export this same exact PEM file again to use with Filezilla and other SSH programs.

Every single command I've tried, exports a single PEM file that says "Private Key" and not "RSA Private Key".

`openssl rsa -in priv.pem -out newkey.pem`

`openssl rsa -in priv.pem -out private_unencrypted.pem -outform PEM`

I've tried dozens of commands, nothing works, and now I'm just throwing things against the wall to see what sticks, and I cannot for the life of me, simply create a file that contains an RSA Private Key and Certificate in PEM format.

Every PEM file I have loaded into Filezilla tells me that it does not contain a private key, even though when manually opening the file, I can see that it does. So I assume it's in the incorrect format.

Comment: In OpenSSL 3.0.* to get 'RSA PRIVATE KEY' format, **use `rsa -traditional` _or_ `pkey -traditional`** (with _either_ `-in` or stdin redirection/piping and similarly `-out` _or_ stdout redirection/piping). This was not true of versions before 2022 which is why you will find gajillions of websites and old As on several Stacks telling you just `rsa` (ditto). And SSH, including FileZilla SFTP, doesn't use any certificate. But this is not programming or development, which is now the scope of StackOverflow.